SPRING NEO4J :: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.my_buzz.core_api_server.dtos.item.ItemDetail] to type [org.neo4j.driver.Value]
Below is my code as per my project ::
> I have below configurations ::

@Configuration
class Neo4jConfig {
    @Bean
    fun neo4jConversions(): Neo4jConversions? {
        val additionalConverters: Set<GenericConverter?> = Collections.singleton(DtoToNeo4jValueConverter())
        return Neo4jConversions(additionalConverters)
    }
}


class DtoToNeo4jValueConverter : GenericConverter {
    override fun getConvertibleTypes(): Set<ConvertiblePair>? {
        val convertiblePairs: MutableSet<ConvertiblePair> = HashSet()
        convertiblePairs.add(ConvertiblePair(ItemDetail::class.java, Value::class.java))
        convertiblePairs.add(ConvertiblePair(Value::class.java, ItemDetail::class.java))
        return convertiblePairs
    }

    override fun convert(@Nullable source: Any?, sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor): Any? {
        return if (ItemDetail::class.java.isAssignableFrom(sourceType.type)) {
            // generic way of converting an object into a map
            val dataclassAsMap = jacksonObjectMapper().convertValue(source as ItemDetail, object :
                TypeReference<Map<String, Any>>() {})
            Values.value(dataclassAsMap)
        } else {
            return convertToNeo4jItemDetailType(source as ItemDetail)
        }
    }

    private fun convertToNeo4jItemDetailType(source: ItemDetail): Neo4jItemDetail {
        println("I came here ....")

        return Neo4jItemDetail(
            ....
        ) // neo4j primitive type data class 
    }
}



convertToNeo4jItemDetailType methods println never gets called, which should be as per my understanding or else it should have auto converted as per the overriden convert function above.


No matter what I do I always get the exception as No converter found capable of converting from type [com.my_buzz.core_api_server.dtos.item.ItemDetail] to type [org.neo4j.driver.Value]


I am not getting any solution over google from the spring community for the same, And I am really fed by now ... please get me out of this trouble else I have to switch to other framework


This does not answer your question, but it does not make sense for convertToNeo4jItemDetailType to take an ItemDetail parameter, since your convert will only call that method if source is NOT an ItemDetail (and is presumably a Value). Also, you do not need to use the return keyword inside that else block.

@cybersam as per my understanding convertToNeo4jItemDetailType should be a custom converter and it should receive a source object of type that its trying to convert, hence its valid, and that return keyword is a part of debugging session as the println in convertToNeo4jItemDetailType method.
Apart from everything the control never reaches to convertToNeo4jItemDetailType  and so the println never executes, that is the main problem here. And as per the exception it can be known that the control doesn't even reach overriden convert method as if it as never loaded to the application context.

I think you are missing my points (and, as I said, I am not trying to answer your question, but am pointing obvious errors). The else in convert() is only called if (ItemDetail::class.java.isAssignableFrom(sourceType.type)) is false, so convertToNeo4jItemDetailType should not take an ItemDetail. And the return in that else block is not syntactically required.
